# How to determine implemented interfaces for jms connection factories using Spring 3.2.1, Jboss AS7, Aspectj 1.7.1 java 1.7?

Tags: jboss7.x, aspectj, java-7, spring-3, hornetq

We are developing a project in java 1.6 using JBOSS AS7 and we use among others: Aspectj and HornetQ.
We need to upgrade to java 1.7 so we use ASpectj 1.7.1. During the deployment we get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
  Error creating bean with name 'eventsJmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/company/project/jms/jms.xml]: 
  Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jmsConnectionFactory' while setting bean property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory': 
  Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; 
    nestedexception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
      warning can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type 
    com.company.project.aspects.MBeanAttributesAdvice [Xlint:cantFindType]
```

The mbean is:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jmsConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/JmsXA" />
```

On other project, We had the same exception when we use a JPA datasource:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/table" />
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
```

and we manage to solve the issue by adding on jboss-deployment-structure the module depedency: org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

is there any module that we can add in order to pass this exception? or any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: It's being hard for me to identify where HornetQ is involved in your issue. it seems a pure spring configuration issue for me.

Comment: This is true! It was aspects issue! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would like to share with you the solution. Add the modules: org.hornetq, org.hornetq.ra , org.jboss.ejb3, org.jboss.ejb-client.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding 
            some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" />
            <module name="org.hornetq" />
            <module name="org.hornetq.ra" />
            <module name="org.jboss.ejb3" />
            <module name="org.jboss.ejb-client" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to document what works for me, even if I'm late to this question.

I'm using JBoss 7.1.1 and Spring 3.2.4:

Using, say, annotation based Aspects in your Spring setup will cause the Aspect-Weaver try to go over *all* components you have, including those you got via JNDI-lookup. The Weaver will stumble over those components, since (I read that somewhere) the Classloader used to load them (JBoss' ModuleClassLoader in my case) will know nothing about my Aspect (living in my project's classloader) and fail with `Xlint:cantFindType`.

Proxying those components by something within the realm of the project's Classloader solves this problem.

For JDBC datasources:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDS" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

For JMS ConnectionFactory

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="connectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/JmsXA" proxy-interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
```

And so on.

This way I do not have to include any extra modules like `org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters` and such.